# Base64 background image was resolved to relative path in server

Tags: css, base64, background-image

I have some CSS class using Base64 background image like this. It's working fine in local host

```
thead th .both {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAQAAADYWf5HAAAAkElEQVQoz7X QMQ5AQBCF4dWQSJxC5wwax1Cq1e7BAdxD5SL+Tq/QCM1oNiJidwox0355mXnG/DrEtIQ6azioNZQxI0ykPhTQIwhCR+BmBYtlK7kLJYwWCcJA9M4qdrZrd8pPjZWPtOqdRQy320YSV17OatFC4euts6z39GYMKRPCTKY9UnPQ6P+GtMRfGtPnBCiqhAeJPmkqAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

but when I deployed project to server, the url was resolved to relative path:

```
thead th .both {
  background-image: url("/file/relativePath/toCssFile/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAQAAADYWf5HAAAAkElEQVQoz7X QMQ5AQBCF4dWQSJxC5wwax1Cq1e7BAdxD5SL+Tq/QCM1oNiJidwox0355mXnG/DrEtIQ6azioNZQxI0ykPhTQIwhCR+BmBYtlK7kLJYwWCcJA9M4qdrZrd8pPjZWPtOqdRQy320YSV17OatFC4euts6z39GYMKRPCTKY9UnPQ6P+GtMRfGtPnBCiqhAeJPmkqAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You can see example in jsFiddle : [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/black_life1804/pszgsd8c/)

Q : Is there a way to prevent browser resolve url to relative path or make relative path works with Base64 image?

Comment: which server side language you use ?

Comment: I work only in front-end, another team work in back-end and deployment but I think they use Java for server side.

Answer (score 0):

You are baseUrl is only for localhost because that url is present in physical drive.

/file/relativePath/toCssFile/ instead of this mention  you are host with port along with path
background-image: 
url("http://www.some.com/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAQAAADYWf5HAAAAkElEQVQoz7X QMQ5AQBCF4dWQSJxC5wwax1Cq1e7BAdxD5SL+Tq/QCM1oNiJidwox0355mXnG/DrEtIQ6azioNZQxI0ykPhTQIwhCR+BmBYtlK7kLJYwWCcJA9M4qdrZrd8pPjZWPtOqdRQy320YSV17OatFC4euts6z39GYMKRPCTKY9UnPQ6P+GtMRfGtPnBCiqhAeJPmkqAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");